# How to decide bias in Hamiltonian Ising model?

Tags: programming, d-wave, annealing, quantum-computing-for-finance

I am trying to code finance portfolio optimisation problem into a quantum annealer, using the Hamiltonian Ising model. I am using the [dwave](https://sdk-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_neal/reference/sampler.html) module

```
neal.sampler.SimulatedAnnealingSampler.sample_ising
```

**I was wondering how one gets to decide what the bias is?** I don't really get how that works. On the documentation of Dwave it says the following:

[image]

There also was this example code:

```
import neal
>>> sampler = neal.SimulatedAnnealingSampler()
h = {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 0.0}
J = {('a', 'b'): 1.0, ('b', 'c'): 1.0, ('a', 'c'): 1.0}
sampleset = sampler.sample_ising(h, J, num_reads=10)
print(sampleset.first.energy)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solving in Ocean framework goes by modeling the problem into a [BinaryQuadraticModel](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/docs_dimod/intro/intro_bqm.html). The pure quantum samplers natively only understand this model. For the hybrid samplers (Leap) one can model the problem into [DiscreteQuadraticModel](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/concepts/dqm.html).

The *bias* are the linear terms in those models objective functions.  They are derived with respect to the problem after the transformation into a BQM or DQM was done. Finance is a topic in D-Waves [problem solving handbook](https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/handbook_problems.html#cb-probs-finance). There are some papers listed.

So, to get the bias terms the problem first needs a formulation as a constrained optimization problem. Examples are given in the Ocean docs, e.g. for a map coloring problem. There are some tools to derive a BQM from constraint optimization problems (pyqubo or [dwavebinarycsp](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/docs_binarycsp/sdk_index.html) ).
This needs to get transformed into an Ising problem to be used for `neal.sampler.SimulatedAnnealingSampler.sample_ising`. The dimod package provides tools for this task.
The terms really depend on the problem structure.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!